# Show order in Custom status instead of processing

Tags: wordpress

In WooCommerce, if a user places an order, and makes a payment, the order automatically goes into the processing section. Instead of the processing section, the order should go in custom status (Order Received). I will manually move the order to processing.

Is there any code available?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by first registering new statuses then set your status to new orders after purchase.

You can do that by editing your theme (or child theme) *functions.php* file or by using your custom plugin.

**Registering a new status**

Add the following code:

```
function register_order_received_order_status() {
  register_post_status( 'wc-order-received', array(
    'label'                     => 'Order received',
    'public'                    => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
    'exclude_from_search'       => false,
    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Order received (%s)', 'Order received (%s)' )
  ) );
}

// Add custom status to order status list
function add_order_received_to_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
  $new_order_statuses = array();
  foreach ( $order_statuses as $key => $status ) {
    $new_order_statuses[ $key ] = $status;
    if ( 'wc-on-hold' === $key ) {
      $new_order_statuses['wc-order-received'] = 'Order received';
    }
  }
  return $new_order_statuses;
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_order_received_order_status' );
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_order_received_to_order_statuses' );
```

**Change Order Status after Purchase**

```
function change_order_status( $order_id ) {  
  if ( ! $order_id ) {return;}            
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  if( 'processing'== $order->get_status() ) {
    $order->update_status( 'wc-order-received' );
  }
}

add_action('woocommerce_thankyou','change_order_status');
```

Comment: To create a custom status, I use yithemes plugin. I have already created an order-received status. Would you mind which code should I use? Should I use the full code shared by you or half code?

Comment: @James14865 If the custom status is already created, then try the second code only.